# LoadCSS in QlikView Extension Objects

Tags: qlikview

I want to load a style.css file from a sub-folder to my qlikview extension. I know it works from the root folder using the code below:

```
let template = Qva.Remote + "?public=only&name=Extensions/<CustomObject>/"
Qva.LoadCSS(tempate + "style.css")
```

The goal is to manage all css files in a related directory to css files. I've simply added the name of the directory to the load function `Qva.LoadCSS` after putting all my css files into that directory. so all of my css files are in `<CustomObject>/CSS/` but it's not working.

```
let template = Qva.Remote + "?public=only&name=Extensions/<CustomObject>/CSS/"
Qva.LoadCSS(template + "style.css")
```